# Why is does my function return HTTP Error 301?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

So I'm making a function that would return if i can watch a certain anime on in this case Crunchyroll, but after looking for the right solution for a couple of days i could not quite find the answer. And I am very new to webscraping, so i don't have any experience.
Here are the headers i've added. The only one that makes a difference right now is the host header.

```
header = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7',
    'connection': 'keep-alive',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'dnt': '1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'host': 'crunchyroll.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
}
```

And here is the last version i tried. I have already tried to work with the request module, but it keeps giving me the exceeding 20 redirects error. After using 'allow_redirects = False' it gives me the 301 error, but if there is a solution through the request module i'd be happy too.

```
(namelist is for example: [rezero-kara-hajimeru-isekai-seikatsu, rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-, rezero])
for i in namelist:
        
        # Crunchyroll Checker
        Cleanlink = 'https://www.crunchyroll.com/en-gb/'
        attempt = Cleanlink + i
        
        try:
            req = urllib.request.Request(attempt, headers=header)
            cj = CookieJar()
            opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler)
            response = opener.open(req)
            response.close()
            print(response)
        except urllib.request.HTTPError as inst:
            output = format(inst)
            print(output)
```

This code gives me this response:

```
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Permanently
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Permanently
HTTP Error 301: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Permanently
```

So the only thing i need is that the code is able to check if a website exists. For example: https://www.crunchyroll.com/en-gb/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world- should return the 200 code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Crunchyroll has a very strict CloudFlare WAF. If your requests have something fishy, it will give you a hard time right away. Possible reasons why you get 301 are

- Maybe you are requesting behind a proxy
- WAF may check if the requester (urllib, requests module in your case) has javascript enable (so it can tell if requester are bot or real user).

**Solution**

You should use this Python lib to do the request for you. It is a wrapper around requests lib in Python, so we can use it as if using requests module in python.

https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/

**Note**

Even with this lib, you can only send few hundreds requests per few hours. Because WAF will still detect that your IP is requesting too much and block you. Crunchyroll's WAF is nasty.